# FATAL ERROR: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes)

Tags: php, upload-max-filesize

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in /home/---/domains/---/public_html/---/system/storage/cache/e0/e04e1f01ecc413b48d48f7d0acd02b41afe20667628afe21e97945b89e1c590a.php on line 51

I have this error, when I load this in controller/common/header.php:

```
$this->load->controller("account/login");
```

My php.ini:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
register_globals = Off
default_charset = UTF-8
memory_limit = 64M
max_execution_time = 36000
upload_max_filesize = 999M
post_max_size=999M
safe_mode = Off
mysql.connect_timeout = 20
session.auto_start = Off
session.use_only_cookies = On
session.use_cookies = On
session.use_trans_sid = Off
session.cookie_httponly = On
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600
allow_url_fopen = On
;display_errors = 1
;error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Comment: we cant see your code which is consuming the memory causing the error, so i dont know how we are suppose to help you.

Comment: But do you expect your code to need that much memory? if not you probably have a undesirable loop eating memory. eg Recursion.

Comment: My guess is infinite recursion `tried to allocate 8192 bytes` typically when this is a low value that is the reason. If you up the memory above that amount and it still happens, then that's another marker for it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to set your memory limit higher.

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Than reload you webserver.

Comment: I get same problem.

Comment: 268,435,456 Bytes _is_ 256 Megabytes